# What do the colors mean on Better Settlers?

Tags: catan

Answers to this [question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/9656/where-can-i-find-good-tile-layouts-for-settlers-of-catan?newreg=5ce3c03e610e4998bc0153321449183c) about tile layouts for Catan suggests [Better Settlers](http://www.bettersettlers.com/). When I open Better Settlers, the page shows a board setup for Catan. What do the colors in the setup stand for?

My guess:

- maroon/dark red: brick
- dark green: wood
- light green: wheat
- yellow: sheep
- grey: ore

Is that correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The colors surely match the colors of the resource cards and the actual hexes:

- maroon - brick
- dark green - wood
- light green - sheep
- yellow - wheat
- gray - ore

And the blank orange hex would be the desert.

[image: resource cards]

[image: hexes]
<sup>(clockwise from bottom left, that's sheep, wheat, ore, brick, and wood;  the center is desert, and there's an extra wood cut off on the bottom)</sup>

Comment: I am the creator of Better Settlers and I approve this correct answer

:)